Changing background color using ColorScheme in ThemeData in Flutter
How to change background color according to system background using ColorScheme in ThemeData in flutter?
I expect to change background color according to background of system. I know there are other ways. But I want if it is possible to do this using ColorScheme in ThemeData

    explanation:
    - firstly create systemBrightness object initialized by MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context); -> it accept System Brightness.
    - now in ColorScheme.fromSeed() assign systemBrightness to brightness property.
    - when you can switch light theme to dark theme / dark theme to light theme  then it see background color changes successfully
    
    code: 
    Brightness systemBrightness = MediaQuery.platformBrightnessOf(context);
    theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.teal, brightness: systemBrightness,),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),


The Material Design team has provided a package to create color schemes based on the platform's implementation of dynamic color, which is called dynamic_color.
It comes with DynamicColorBuilder which provides a light and dark ColorScheme based on the system's color implementation (which is wallpaper color for Android).
To use it, simply add the package using the flutter pub add dynamic_color command, import the pacakge in your Dart file, and use the builder:
import 'package:dynamic_color/dynamic_color.dart';

// ...

DynamicColorBuilder(
  builder: (ColorScheme? lightDynamic, ColorScheme? darkDynamic) {
    // ...
  }
),

